# F# adding comparison to recursive function that exctracts element from a list of tuples

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a list of tuples cars:

```
let cars : (string * int * string * int) list = [
  ("car1",1400,"manf1",5);
  ("car2",1600,"manf2",6);
  ("car3",2000,"manf3",8);
  ("car4",1200,"manf4",4)]
```

Tuple has following information: *car model, price, manufacturer, no of cylinders*.

I would like to create a function that will have a input of price and list which will provide me with a list of car names where price is higher than input price.

I figured out that I can extract car names like this

```
let rec carPriceFrom (xs : ((string * int * string * int) list)) =
    match xs with
    | (i,s,_,_) :: xs' -> i :: carPriceFrom xs'
    | [] -> []
```

But I can't figure out how to add evaluation that evaluates input p to s (price) in the tuple and outputs only the cars models like this:

```
carPriceFrom cars 1500
```

Which gives a output of list with car2 and car3.

I tried this:

```
let rec carPriceFrom (xs : ((string * int * string * int) list)) p =
    match xs with
    | (i,s,_,_) :: xs' when s > p -> i :: carPriceFrom xs'
    | [] -> []
```

But it doesn't work. How should I add the evaluation of p and s in the match pattern.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? In which way, specifically? Do you get an error? Do you not get the correct output? If so, what do you get? Please try to describe the problem, not just the assignment.

Comment: Sorry, I got an type error:
 error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'string list'    
but here has type
    ''a -> string list'

Answer (score 2):

Pretty close. You need 2 more things to make it work:

1. pass the `p` parameter into the recursive call to `carPriceFrom`
2. add another case (for when `s` is not greater than `p`)

This code works:

```ml
let rec carPriceFrom xs p =
    match xs with
    | (i,s,_,_) :: xs' when s > p -> i :: carPriceFrom xs' p  // we're passing p
    | _ :: xs' -> carPriceFrom xs' p     // new case here
    | [] -> []
```

`carPriceFrom cars 1500` evaluates to:

```
["car2"; "car3"]
```

Run it in [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/KosherSafeRay#main.fs)